# Yii2 validation message doesn't change

Tags: yii2

I have simple ajax validation for email.

```
$rules[] = [['email'], 'unique', "message"=>"Email адресът {value} вече съществува!"];
```

But my custom message doesn't show. It always return default message: `This email address has already been taken`. Any clue why is this? I thought it is as simple as that.Where i am wrong? Btw it is `user dektrium` module if that matters.Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return  the values in

```
public function rules()
{
  return [

   [['email'], 'unique', "message"=>"Email адресът {value} вече съществува!"];

    // the email attribute should be a valid email address
    ['email', 'email'],
  ];
}
```

eventually you should extend or redefine the User Model rules() function